# How to completely sandbox registry and file system for Windows app?

Tags: windows, winapi, sandbox, virtualization, legacy

We have a legacy Windows application which does its job very well. The problem is, it stores and manipulates registry values and files in both AppData and ProgramData Windows folders during runtime, and no source code is available to change it. We need to run multiple copies (they have different settings) of this application simultaneously, which is currently not possible, because they conflict with each other and crash. Creating a separate Windows VM for each copy is not possible (the machines are low-end and simply do not handle it; besides, some users do not have the knowledge for setting up a VM).

How can we completely isolate each copy of the app in its own directory? I thought about intercepting WinAPI calls and replacing calls to the file system and registry with our own database, but I am not sure how to implement this. A brief search gave me [Deviare](https://github.com/nektra/Deviare-InProc) (open-source) and [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) (proprietary). Are these the right tools for the job? If so, which WinAPI functions should be intercepted?

Comment: Some problems don't have solutions. Fixing programs as bad as this from the outside would seem to fall into that category.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you implying that it is impossible to reliably intercept registry and file system calls of a process in Windows?

Comment: Not impossible. Just exceptionally hard and brittle.

Comment: IMHO, the task is not exceptionally hard and brittle but quite labour-intensive instead. @interphx, you could start with ProcessMonitor to detect which functions have to be intercepted.

Comment: Do you use Windows 10? You can try converting your app into Appx (UWP) application and OS will handle virtualization for you. Create few packages with different identities and they will all use separate virtual environments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

Comment: @OlehNechytailo We use Windows 7, but thanks for the link, I didn't know about this Win10 tool.

Comment: There are various sandboxes available, one that comes to mind is [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/). These are propably more lightweight than full-blown VMs as they basically just do registry and filesystem redirection. Some of these even allow you to encapsulate the app including all dependencies into a single standalone executable which is then able to run without installation.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution to this problem is to develop a kernel driver. Starting with WIndows Vista, the kernel allows drivers absolute control over registry and file system operations (look at `CmRegisterCallbackEx` and `FltRegisterFilter` routines, read about registry filter drivers and file system minifilter drivers). However, as said in the comments, doing the sandboxing right is difficult since there are many edge cases and some things are not officially documented (e.g. there is not much information about some types of file system and registry operations available).

In general, hooking API calls in the applications is not a good solutions since the applications may bypass your hooks by simply making direct system calls (the interface for the core system calls, including those implementing file and registry operations, did not change for ages and their numbers may be computed dynamically).

If you trust the application not to do things like direct system calls, you can take advantage of API hooking or using some quite clever routines like (`RegOverridePredefKey` (allows you to change registry root handles for the application, effectively redirecting registry accesses made via `RegXxx` Windows API calls). I am not aware of anything similar for easy file system redirection.

Comment: `RegOverridePredefKey` only applies to the current process. So you would have to do DLL injection for instance to run it in the other process immediately after launch.

Comment: Well, the same applies to API hooking, so I thought it unnecessary to mention this.

Comment: _The problem is, it stores and manipulates registry values and files in both AppData and ProgramData_ ... just an idea: use `RegOverridePredefKey` to redirect registry and then modify the registry values that define the locations of _AppData_ and _ProgramData_ folders ([HKLM|HKCU]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders).

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but there is a quite new solution - Windows Sandbox (win10 pro and up).
You can have a sandbox BOOM - just like that.

take moment to read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-architecture

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-configure-using-wsb-file

It is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sandboxing solution, such as SHADE Sandbox.
It runs programs in isolated environment and roughly speaking, redirects all operations with files and registry to a virtual copy of those files and registry keys. A redirecting fs and registry driver sits at its core, as described above ("the general solution")

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/downloads/)? This is a lightweight virtualization environment, redirects all file and registry access to separate files.